# Magento - Does simple product have tier pricing?

Tags: php, magento

How would I check if a simple product has tier pricing from the product view template page?  I could output the tier prices and check if that list is empty but I'd like to do it server side and wondered if there was a function in place to accomplish this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php you can get the tierprices with `$product->getTierPrice()`.

This returns an array with tierprices. If array is empty, then the product has no tier pricing. Else, it has.

Comment: Thank you! That's just what I was after.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
if(count($product->getTierPrice()) > 0) {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably a more efficient solution, as it shouldn't require loading all the price data:

```
if ($product->getTierPriceCount() > 0) {
    // your code
}
```